# How to Pass DatepickerIOS Date Object to Firebase (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm EXTREMELY new at coding, and I took Grinder's course on React Native. I have no idea how to save the datepickerios date object into Firebase. I'm pretty sure something in this code here is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, if anyone's looking for a mentee, I'd be grateful for your help. Thanks!

```
class ScoreForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {chosenDate: new Date()};

        this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
      }

      setDate(newDate) {
        this.setState({chosenDate: newDate});
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            <CardSection>
                    <Text style={styles.pickerTextStyle}>Enter Date</Text>
                 </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    {/* <Input
                        label="Date"
                        placeholder="MM/DD/YY"
                        value={this.props.date}
                        onChangeText={value => this.props.scoreUpdate({ prop: 'date', value })}
                    /> */}

                    <DatePickerIOS
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        mode='date'
                        date={this.state.chosenDate}
                        onDateChange={value => this.props.scoreUpdate({ prop: 'date', value })}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                        label="Score"
                        placeholder="Add Number"
                        value={this.props.score}
                        onChangeText={value => this.props.scoreUpdate({ prop: 'score', value })}
                    />                    
                </CardSection>
            </View>
        );
     }
    }

    const styles = {
      pickerTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 20
      }
    };

       const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       const { date, score } = state.scoreForm;

       return { date, score };
     };

    export default connect(null, { scoreUpdate }) (ScoreForm);
```

Since I am using Redux, I'm assuming I that I don't want to store it in state, correct? Here is the this.props.ScoreUpdate action:

```
export const scoreUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
    return {
        type: SCORE_UPDATE,
        payload: { prop, value }
    };
};
```

Comment: Do you want to save the value in state?? and can you share `this.props.scoreUpdate ` action code that would be moe helpful

Comment: If I'm using Redux, there shouldn't be a reason to save in state, correct? I added the action code above. Thanks @Maneesh